# Capturing touch on concave/convex images with libgdx

Tags: android, touch, libgdx, concave, convex

I'm creating an app that uses libgdx in Android.

I need to add a touch listener for when the end user clicks only on the visible part of a texture, whether it's concave or convex image.

How can I do that?

I remember that there is a nice idea (though I never saw an implementation of it) that for each texture, you provide a unique color and is drawn with this color for its visible part before drawing its real content, and if the touch is done on the color, it means that the end user has clicked on the image. Is it possible to use the same technique for libgdx? If so, how?

The same goes, of course, for images that I choose to rotate/scale.

Comment: Show us the code of how you are displaying the textures on the Android screen. Show what you've attempted so far as an onClick!

Comment: it doesn't matter . i will change my code to whatever way it is needed to be . as an example , you see the libgdx sample : http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list , or more precise : http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/detail?name=gdx-helloworld-0.9.2.zip&can=2&q=